# Проблема getElementsByTagName в php DomDocument

Tags: php, dom

Есть вот такой код на `php`. С помощью `DOMDocument` ищу все теги `img` потом прохожу в цикле над ними и делаю изменение.

Проблема в том что в `html` с которым я работаю есть 5 тегов `img`. А цикл проходит 3 раза.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$imgs_t = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$amp_img_src = '/images/front/what_is_dt_video.jpg';
$count_foreach = 0;
foreach( $imgs_t as $img_t ){
    $count_foreach++;
    $img_alt = '';
    $tmp_img_src = $img_t->getAttribute('src');
    $img_alt = $img_t->getAttribute('alt');

    if($tmp_img_src != $amp_img_src){                
        $tmp_amp_img = $dom->createElement('amp-img');
        $tmp_amp_img->setAttribute('width', 200);
        $tmp_amp_img->setAttribute('height', 200);
        $tmp_amp_img->setAttribute('src', $tmp_img_src);
        $tmp_amp_img->setAttribute('alt', $img_alt);

        $img_t->parentNode->replaceChild($tmp_amp_img, $img_t);
    }
}
var_dump($count_foreach);
```

А это именно тот `html` который входит в переменную `$html` в начале `php` кода.

```
<div class="what_is_dt drop_down_pg">
    <div class="drop_down_video drop_down_cont">
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <div class="video_wrap">
                <div id="ntx_dt_info_video_link" class="no-padding">
                    <img src="/images/front/what_is_dt_video.jpg" height="315px" width="481px" alt="Lorem ipsum">
                </div>
                <div class="what_fx_video_head">
                    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 no-padding">

            <span class="background_green">

                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                <p><em>Lorem ipsum</em></p>
                <p><em>Lorem ipsum</em></p>
            </span>
            [T]CONFIRM_THEORY[/T]
        </div>
        [T]CONFIRM_THEORY_MOBILE[/T]
        <hr />
    </div>
    <h2 style="margin-top: 40px;"><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></h2>
    <div style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <div class="signature-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="/uploads/docs/th%20Failure%20Swing.png" alt="Lorem ipsum" title="Lorem ipsum" width="200" height="200" />
            <span style="font-size: small;"> <strong>Lorem ipsum.</strong></span>
            <span style="font-size: small;">Lorem ipsum. </span>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="/uploads/docs/th%20Nonfailure%20Swing.png" alt="Lorem ipsum" width="200" height="200"/>
            <span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Lorem ipsum.</strong> </span>
            <span style="font-size: small;">Lorem ipsum.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p style="clear: both; padding-top: 30px;" >Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <div style="padding-top: 30px;">
        <div class="signature-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="/uploads/docs/th Failure Swing Bottom.png" alt="" />
            <p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Failure Swing </strong>Lorem ipsum.</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="/uploads/docs/th Nonfailure Swing Bottom.png" alt="Lorem ipsum" width="200" height="200" />
            <p><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>Nonfailure Swing</strong>Lorem ipsum.</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p style="clear: both;"><br /></p>
    [T]OUR_LEARNING[/T]
</div>
```

Comment: проблема в изменении структуры DOM в цилке. пока правда не понял еще, как именно это влияет. пропускает все четные элементы

Comment: @teran Спасибо хоть чем то помогли. Если будут еще идеи с удовольствием послушаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в общем и целом проблема выглядит вот так, если сократить до минимального примера.

```
$html = <<<HTML
    <div class="what_is_dt drop_down_pg">       
        <img src="1">
        <img src="2">
        <img src="3">
        <img src="4">
        <img src="5">
    </div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$imgs_t = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
print_r($imgs_t);

$amp_img_src = '/images/front/what_is_dt_video.jpg';
$count_foreach = 0;
foreach( $imgs_t as $img_t ){
    $count_foreach++;
    $tmp_img_src = $img_t->getAttribute('src');

    print_r([$count_foreach, $tmp_img_src]);

    if($tmp_img_src != $amp_img_src){
        $tmp_amp_img = $dom->createElement('amp-img');
        $img_t->parentNode->replaceChild($tmp_amp_img, $img_t);
    }
}
```

что тут происходит. вы находите все 5 элементов. начинаете перебор. На первой итерации выполняется условие и вы заменяете первый узел. дальше бы должен быть переход ко второму узлу исходной коллекции, но она у нас изменена, и теперь второй узел измененной коллекции будет соответствовать третьему узлу исходной. таким образом второй узел исходной у нас как бы теряется. Как именно и что ломается я полностью объяснить не могу, но вопрос к реализации итератора.

В целом вы можете менять структуру если будете проходить эту коллекцию в обратном порядке. Тут в принципе такая классическая проблема удаления элементов массиве в цикле, если удаляете, обрабатывайте в обратном порядке, тогда удаление узлов никак не скажется на индексации массива еще не обработанных элементов

```
$len = $imgs_t->length;

for($i = $len-1; $i >=0 ; $i--){
    $count_foreach++;
    $img_t = $imgs_t->item($i);
    ...  
}
```

---

если представить, что наша коллекция была

```
A B C D E
```

выполняем первую итерацию. индекс итератора `0`, элемент `А`. Мы удаляем этот элемент, и коллеакция становится

```
B C D E
```

переходим к новой итерации, счетчик итератора ничего не знает, и увеличивается на `1`. Извлекаем этот элемент и получаем `C`. 
В итоге получаем, что за счет удаления(замены) первого элемента мы теряем элемент `B`. В случае обработки коллекции в обратно порядке такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: Все понятно, кроме одного после того как я меняю один элемент, после  не должен меняться второй узел, ведь мы работаем еще с первой.

Comment: а второй и не меняется. он просто пропускается. при новой итерации счетчик (внутренний счетчик итератора nodelist) увеличивается и становится равным 2 и это применяется уже к новой коллекции из 4х элементов, сдвинутой влево так сказать на 1. 
у меня сегодня что-то проблемы с изложением мыслей :D

Comment: Понял что вы имеете ввиду. но вообще то это не должно было влиять на счетчик цикла.

Comment: в общем тут проблема  в том, что мы работаем не с массивом, а со списком. в массиве, если бы заменили один элемент на другой, то проблемы бы не возникло. здесь же на каждой итерации происходит а-ля `$i++` и `$list->item($i)`.

Comment: @RazGalstyan на счетчик цикла ничего и не влияет (то есть само по себе удаление, если вы об этом). Просто индекс новой коллекции и старой не совпадают.

Comment: Вот теперь понятно ))))

Comment: @RazGalstyan дополнил немного ответ.